# Is it possible to complete snap installation without rebooting

Tags: snap, raspberrypi

I'm writing a snap-store install script for RPiOS.
the [official documentation](https://snapcraft.io/docs/installing-snap-on-raspbian) says to reboot after installing `snapd` with `apt`, I tried and saw that it isn't necessary to reboot at this point. so I proceeded to install snap core and snap-store.
but now I have a problem. the menu shortcut for snap-store doesn't appear until I reboot.
my question: can I make the snap-store menu shortcut appear without rebooting?

any help is appreciated!

**the documentation I used:**

- [installing snap on RPiOS](https://snapcraft.io/docs/installing-snap-on-raspbian)
- [installing snap-store](https://snapcraft.io/docs/installing-snap-store-app)

Comment: I'm not sure you're on-topic, as RPIOS is definitely off-topic (refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic).   I'd have gone to the SnapCraft forum for *snap* questions anyway...

Comment: ok, I realized that and asked in the snap forums. thanks anyway.